# Send SMS to Multiple numbers using android programatically

Tags: android, arraylist, telephonymanager, smsmanager

I have attached my code below here.Which is working fine on Samsung device.The SMS was sent to all the numbers at the same time this is not working for some devices such as OPPO, REDMI, VIVO the SMS has not deliver to some numbers it only sending to a 1st number of a list.It would be grateful for your help.

```
private void startSendMessages() {

    registerBroadCastReceivers();

    mMessageSentCount = 0;

    sendSMS(MobNumber.get(mMessageSentCount).toString(), str_Address);
}

private void sendNextMessage() {
    if (thereAreSmsToSend()) {
        sendSMS(MobNumber.get(mMessageSentCount).toString(), str_Address);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All SMS have been sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private boolean thereAreSmsToSend() {
    return mMessageSentCount < MobNumber.size();
}

private void sendSMS(final String phoneNumber, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
    mMessageSentTotalParts = parts.size();

    Log.i("Message Count", "Message Count: " + mMessageSentTotalParts);

    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    for (int j = 0; j < mMessageSentTotalParts; j++) {
        sentIntents.add(sentPI);
        deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
    }

    mMessageSentParts = 0;
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
}

private void registerBroadCastReceivers() {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    mMessageSentParts++;
                    if (mMessageSentParts == mMessageSentTotalParts) {
                        mMessageSentCount++;
                        sendNextMessage();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {

                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

}
```

Comment: I can see that you are sending SMS one by one, not all the same time. So debug the code and check if it sending all the message to all the numbers one by one.
Check android version on redmi if they are above Marshmallow then request for the permission

Comment: Thanks for your comment.shall i know where i have to call the permission in above code???

Comment: Before calling startSendMessages()

Answer (score 0):

This way you can request permissions

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                // You don't have the permission you need to request it
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
            }else{
                // You have the permission.
            }
```

and you will receive the response on onRequestPermissionsResult. Override this method

Comment: still it sends to first no of the list.tested from oppo.

Comment: @RameshYogu Have you done debugging? Is loop is executing for each no? If yes, then check in on receive if you are getting the result.